# How to Insert Multiple row to multiple table at a once into database

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

There are three table as t1, t2 and t3.
I'm trying to insert my row to multiple table using CodeIgniter as given above.

**Code:**

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name' ,
      'email' => 'E-mail'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name' ,
      'email' => 'E-mail'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title 2' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
      'email' => 'E-mail 2'
   )
);

$i=1;
for($k=0;$k<3;$k++){
      $this->db->insert_batch('t'.$i++, $data); 
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: i have tried what is mention as above.

Comment: Don't you get an `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`error?

Comment: now its run and insert into table at once

Answer (score 3):

I hope , this stuff will work for you, just try this.

```
$data = array(
    array(
          'title' => 'My title' ,
          'name' => 'My Name' ,
          'email' => 'E-mail'
    ),
    array(
          'title' => 'Another title' ,
          'name' => 'Another Name' ,
          'email' => 'E-mail'
    ),
    array(
          'title' => 'Another title 2' ,
          'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
          'email' => 'E-mail 2'
    )
);

$i=1;
for($k=0;$k<3;$k++)
{
   $this->db->insert_batch('t'.$i++, $data); 
}
```